# Raspberry Pi wild boar reppelent

Tags: arduino, electronics, battery

In my father's farm, he may face a problem with wild boars. There are currently too many of them around. They already came to my father's farm but they did not destroy anything (there's not much to destroy atm) but we are expecting them to come when the season of corn, potatoes, etc is more advanced than it is now. It's a small farm but provides food for the entire year and some boars can destroy a lot of property in a single night.

We have some solutions, but i tought of a much cheaper (and non-intrusive) idea but i need some feedback. This idea was based on a farmer on a close by village that has a system which makes a gun sound every 20 minutes during the night.

What i want to try to implement is a similar system but with **Raspberry Pi and/or Arduino**.

**The pre-requesites of this possible system are:**

- Fully autonumous using solar panel(s).
- Recharge batteries during the day.
- Stop recharging batteries when full.
- Working hours: 10 pm to 7 am.
- Recharging hours: 7 am to 8 pm.
- Play gun sound every 20 minutes (10 pm to 7 am).
- Speaker should be heard 200 meters away from it's position (assuming almost no background noise).

My first idea based on research i made is:
 [image: Solution 1]

I need feedback on the **idea above** or if it is completly wrong another possible solution for this problem.

Comment: As interesting as the question is, it is too broad for the Q&A style of the site. I'm sure someone will go to the effort to provide a decent answer to this question, but do not be surprised if your question is closed. That being said for a new user to the site you have formatted this question very clearly, and that is very much appreciated.

Comment: Ok i'll try to ask elsewhere. Still don't know where but i'll figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of Raspberry Pi forums out there where you might have more luck finding answers. However, if you get stuck on something this site is good place to ask *specific* questions.

Comment: Note that specific details of a "broad" question could make good questions themselves. Some might even have been asked here before, e.g. solar powered Pi's. Maybe you look into the various aspects again, look around at the site and come up with more distinct questions.

Comment: @RuiAlves, some parts of this question could be good fits for the [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com) Stack.  Just check out our [help center](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help) and take our [tour](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tour) to ensure that you have narrowed down your question(s) sufficiently to the scope of the site.  Hope to see you over there!

Comment: Why not use the Arduino to play the sound? There are plenty of shields for the Arduino that can play sounds, I don't see the need for a full RPi here...

Comment: @anonymous2 will do.

Comment: @RonBeyer yeah you're right. But i'm not expert on hardware and it was just a starting idea.